# Can not deploy Cloud Function with language_tool_python in Python 3.7 runtime

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, google-cloud-functions, languagetool

How you use language tool in Google Cloud Function? I'm trying to deploy in GCP Cloud Function with runtime Python 3.7. I could use the library using my local virtual environment where I have java installed.

But when  I'm trying to deploy it in Cloud Function, I'm getting **ModuleNotFoundError: No java install detected. Please install java to use language-tool-python.**

I'm using the language_tool_python library in the cloud function

```py
# install and import for grammar accuracy
import language_tool_python
tool = language_tool_python.LanguageTool('en-IN')
matches = tool.check(input_string)
```

in the requirement.txt we have --

```
language-tool-python==2.4.5
```

I'm getting the following error message --

```py
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file main.py can't be loaded. Did you list all required modules in requirements.txt? Detailed stack trace: Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker_v2.py", line 359, in check_or_load_user_function _function_handler.load_user_function() 
File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker_v2.py", 
 line 236, in load_user_function spec.loader.exec_module(main_module) File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/user_code/main.py", line 10, in <module> from libraries.unknown_word import word_meaning File "/user_code/libraries/unknown_word.py", line 18, in <module> tool = language_tool_python.LanguageTool('en-IN') 
File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/language_tool_python/server.py", line 46, in __init__ self._start_server_on_free_port() File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/language_tool_python/server.py", line 183, in _start_server_on_free_port self._start_local_server() 
File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/language_tool_python/server.py", line 193, in _start_local_server download_lt() File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/language_tool_python/download_lt.py", line 144, in download_lt confirm_java_compatibility() 
File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/language_tool_python/download_lt.py", line 75, in confirm_java_compatibility 
raise ModuleNotFoundError('No java install detected. Please install java to use language-tool-python.') 
ModuleNotFoundError: No java install detected. Please install java to use language-tool-python.
```

Can anyone please provide a solution how to use LanguageTool from server less functions?

How can we have java environment in Cloud Function along with Python 3.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation prerequisite](https://pypi.org/project/language-tool-python/) is clear, Python 3.7 and Java 8.0+ are required.

And, with cloud functions, you can't have a custom runtime (at least, not yet), and thus you can't have Java and Python on the same runtime environment.

For this, I recommend you to use [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs). It's very similar to Cloud Function but, because you have to build your own container, you can customize the runtime environment as you want.
To switch from one to the other, I [wrote an article on this (my first one!)](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-and-cloud-function-what-i-use-and-why-12bb5d3798e1)